# i don't understand the figure tag exactly

Tags: html

I don't understand the figure tag from HTML 5 exactly. i have searched on internet but i sill don't understand some things.

I know that you can use figure tag for images like photos etc. But I am wondering: must I put the images like small icons or logos in the figure tag too and can I nest a figure inside a figure tag? or more images in one figure?

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The `<figure>` tag is just a specially named `<div>`.  It normally contains one `<img>` tag and one `<figcaption>` tag.  The idea is that it provides a specially named container for an image and its caption so that it is easier to style.  I do not think figure tags were meant to be nested.  Think about a book.  There is normally only one image and caption per figure.  Not every image needs to be enclosed in the `<figure>` tag.  In fact, no images have to be.  In short, you do not have to use the `<figure>` tag, but when you do, the syntax looks like this:

```
<figure>
    <img src='image.png'>
    <figcaption>This is the caption.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: can i use the figure tag without a caption? when i used it for an images which doesn't need a title (caption). like this: <figure><img src='image.png'><figure>is this wrong?

Comment: That is fine too.  It does not require a caption.  However, at that point it becomes an extra tag that is not really doing anything.  If you have a bunch of images that do have a caption and a couple that don't, I enclose them all in `<figure>` tags to be consistent, but otherwise I would leave it off.